# Why the random function in java is always generating high values?

Tags: java, random, automated-tests, probability

I am implementing a test data generator in java that uses to generate random values for java primitive types. 
The range of possible parameters values is not limited. For example, if I want to generate a random integer or float I will consider all possible values (MAX_INT-MIN_INT). To do so, I am using stuff like :

- Random().nextInt()
- Random().nextLong()
- Random().nextFloat()*Float.MAX_VALUE
- Random().nextDouble()*Double.MAX_VALUE
- And so on...

However, doing like this, I note that the generated values are always high (close to the max and low value of the parameter type). After 100000 iteration for example, the random operator didn't generate a value in the range [-1000 - 1000]. The same thing for floats, longs. etc,...

Can you give me an explanation of how the random operator is performing in Java? Why the generated values are always high when we consider all possible values of the Java type?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to summarize big number of generated values. Since it has uniform distribution, overall sum will tend to 0.

Comment: The probability is one in 2.15 million, so I suggest you retry with 10 million draws or so and you should see a few of those numbers appearing...

Comment: There are lots of big numbers, and not many small numbers, so of course you get big numbers more often than small numbers. (You did ask for a uniform distribution...)

Comment: Yes I think so, it is a matter of probability

Comment: protected int genInteger(Parameter p) {
  return new Random().nextInt();
 }
 protected float genFloat(Parameter p) {
  return (2*(new Random().nextFloat())-1)*Float.MAX_VALUE;
 }
 protected long genLong(Parameter p) {
  return new Random().nextLong();
 }

Here the code snippet . 

I found that it is a bit wired because after 10000 iterations, it couldn't generate at least one single value between [-1000 - 1000].

However, when I display the generated values, I can see that they are always close to the limit either to the MAX or to the MIN. How can you explain that ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your preception of "high" and "low" is wrong.

The probability of a single value (assuming uniform distribution) to be in `[-1000,1000]` is `2001/(MAX_INT-MIN_INT)`, which is around 0.00000046.

This probability is extremely small, and thus also the expected number of "small" variables will be small.

In fact, in uniform distribution over `[MIN_INT,MAX_INT]`, approximately half of the element will be positive - and half negative.

Similarly, only quarter of them will be between `0` to `MAX_INT/2` (which is much higher than 1000 as you know).

If you want more "low" values, narrow yourself to smaller range of elements, or use non uniform distribution that is expected to generate more values closer to 0 ([gaussian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) for exmaple).

---

Have a look at this code snippest:

```
       int count1 = 0, count2=0;
       for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) { 
           float x = genFloat(null);
           if (x < 1E38 && x > 0) count1++;
           if (x > Float.MAX_VALUE - 1E38) count2++;
       }
       System.out.println(count1);
       System.out.println(count2);
```

It generates 10000 random floats, and checks how much are in `[0,1E38]`, and how much are in `[MAX-1E38,MAX]`

Note that when talking about floats, the theoretical probability of each is ~1/(2*MAX) ~= 14.7%.

And as you can see, both "close to 0" and "close to MAX" in the same range has similar empirical number of variables produced in their ranges.

Comment: @staticx Define "close to the limit of MIN or MAX - how close? are they between MAX-1000 to MAX?

Comment: I mean close to the Float Max and Min Value (the same for long type)

Comment: @staticx `int count1 = 0, count2=0;
     for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) { 
      float x = genFloat(null);
      if (x < 1000 && x > 0) count1++;
      if (x > Float.MAX_VALUE - 1000) count2++;
     }
     System.out.println(count1);
     System.out.println(count2);` results in both being 0 to me. Your prespective is wrong. You think MAX-100000 is "close to MAX" but 100000 is not small, in uniform distribution, there is same chance to be in [0,100000] and in [MAX-100000,MAX]

Comment: Thank you, in fact yes the result is 0. What do you suggest so ? I need to explore the range of all possible values within Float or Integer values with the same probability

Comment: @staticx I am not sure what do you want to do exactly, I have no idea what "explore the range of possible values within float or integer" means. I suggested two alternatives (different distribution/different range). More info will be needed if you want something else, and I believe it will be out of scope for this question.

Comment: maybe I should use other kind of random distributions in Java. Do you know other ways to generate values within [max range - min range]?
in java of course

Comment: @staticx You can explore the [Random.nextGaussian()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextGaussian()) method, it might help you.

Comment: something like r.nextGaussian() * Integer.MAX_VALUE ?